# Z3Prover/z3 installation fails

Tags: ocaml, z3

I am trying to install z3(https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3)
I have run the following command.

```
> python ./scripts/mk_make.py --ml --prefix=D:/winz3 -g
```

I am getting this exception.

> *File "./scripts/mk_make.py", line 18, in 
>       mk_bindings(API_files)   File "/cygdrive/e/OCamal Programming/Installer/Jan 2019/Z3/z3-master/scripts/mk_util.py", line
>   3280, in mk_bindings
>       check_ml()   File "/cygdrive/e/OCamal Programming/Installer/Jan 2019/Z3/z3-master/scripts/mk_util.py", line 480, in check_ml
>       raise MKException('Failed testing ocamlopt compiler. Set environment variable OCAMLOPT with the path to the Ocaml native
>   compiler. Note that ocamlopt may require flexlink to be in your
>   path.')
>
> mk_exception.MKException: 'Failed testing ocamlopt compiler.
>   Set environment variable OCAMLOPT with the path to the Ocaml native
>   compiler. Note that ocamlopt may require flexlink to be in your
>   path.'*

I have added the environment variable and also the path to flexdll(C:\Program Files (x86)\flexdl\flexlink.exe)

Please suggest what else i can try.

Comment: Perhaps additionally make sure that ocamlopt is executable in the shell by setting the PATH variable. Alternatively, you could try the CMake based build process - afaik the python based build system is being phased out.

Comment: Also if you are running under cygwin, it's often safer to stick to the unix notation (replace D:/winz3 by /cygdrive/e/winz3) but I don't think this has an influence here.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x I tried CMake build process. Installation was successful. 
However when i run ocamfind list command, Z3 was not listed .
Am i missing any configuration here ?

Comment: I've never compiled the ocaml bindings of z3, I'll check if my installation generated them but I believe it's not the case.